# Ajax upload not working in ie

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajax-upload, ajaxuploader

I am using ajax upload for uploading a image .it is working in all browser but not working in IE.

here is my code what i m using,

```
  $('#photoimg').live('change', function(){ 
    $(".selectedphoto").html('');
    $(".selectedphoto").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '.selectedphoto',
                    success:       onsuccess,

    }).submit();

        })';
```

HTML

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" class="required" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's not working? **Does it start to upload the image or it just never starts?** Can you show us how you are loading the javascript files (both jquery and the one you posted here)

Comment: It never start,after selecting the file nothing is happening.

Comment: what about the `<script>` tags? Post them in the exact order you are adding them and where (in the `<head>`, after the `</body>`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed you are using the jQuery Form Plugin.

If you check https://github.com/malsup/form/ you will find that it mentions that this plugin is dependent on XHR 2 for modern browsers (in case of IE it is only possible in IE10+) and for older versions it uses iframes (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

It is suggested that you check the above link on the iframe part as it involves a bit of understanding of how the server can access the file.

Let us know if it worked and what version of IE you were testing.

Comment: This seems more like general instruction and a request for more info than a specific answer to the problem. This should have been a comment.